# Add information below picture in moderncv casual style

Tags: titles, moderncv

I would like to add additional info below the picture in `moderncv`'s `casual` style, as seen in the picture. Right now, I naively added this info in `moderncvstylecasual.sty` to the `\makecvtitle` command. Of course, this causes the optional title to go down, I would like them to be next to each other.
What is the right way to do this?

[image: addition info]

Comment: Is there any code that produced the above picture?

Answer (score 3):

The following patch to `\makecvtitle` in the `casual` style of [`moderncv](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) inserts a sub-photo caption with zero height (via`\smash`). As such, it doesn't influence the vertical displacement of other resume content.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}% <cmd>
  {\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}% <search>
  {\leavevmode\rlap{\smash{\small% Adjust font style/size
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\@photowidth}@{}}
     \\ \rule{0pt}{1.5\normalbaselineskip}%
     some \\ picture \\ information% Your picture information here
   \end{tabular}}}%
   \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

Place the above code snippet somewhere in your preamble *after* `\moderncvstyle{casual}` and *before* `\begin{document}`.